# Amazon RDS MySQL limitations

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-ec2

I intend to use Amazon RDS MySQL with one db.t2.micro instance.

Are there any limitations of max_connections and max_questions ?

I searched on the Internet and I found that there is a default value for max_connections, but I can change it through parameters, is this correct ?

And I didn't find anything about max_questions.

Can I set any value for max_connections and max_questions ? Or I am limited to a certain value ?

Thanks

Comment: At least the  max_connections can be changed through a parameter group.  Practical maximum depends on available memory.

Comment: An FYI ... [mysql instapaper outage](https://medium.com/making-instapaper/instapaper-outage-cause-recovery-3c32a7e9cc5f) - `caused by a 2TB file size limit for RDS instances created before April 2014`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these values can be changed (within limits).

### 1. max_connections

You can change this value via parameter groups. The maximum allowed value is 100 000. Note that you are also constrained by available memory (1 GB in your case).

### 2. max_questions

This value is stored per user in the `mysql` database table `user`. The default value is 0, which means "unlimited". The column type is `INT`, so the maximum value is 4294967295.

You can check the current values like this:

```
SELECT `User`,`max_questions` FROM `mysql`.`user`;
```

Comment: For db.t2.micro instance what is the max_questions limit ?

Comment: I added info about max_questions.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but if I were going to do MySQL on AWS (which I am), I would use the MySQL variant of Aurora. It's a very nice database engine with a language that is completely compatible with MySQL. I'm running Jira and Fisheye on a small instance with no problems and it only uses 25% of the instance.